# Fragments getting created before billing information is fetched

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am observing a very weird behavior. I am having 4 fragments in my Activity. There is in-app billing code writter as well. Whenever i click on a fragment to view the elements inside it, the in-app billing code is also triggered.

I have incorporated the in-app billing code provided by [Google Android](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html).

First time i click on a fragment the in-app billing code is triggered and i get to know whether the user is premium or not (I am maintaining a static variable to maintain that information. I am setting that information in that variable). After that the fragment code is initiated and certain features are enabled.

Next time i click on a fragment, the fragment code is triggered first and somehow (dunno how) the variable is again reset ! So, i see all old features. After i am into the fragment views, the in-app billing code is triggered and the variable is again set to premium (which is useless now).

After that all consequent clicks on fragment behave the latter way.

Any reason as to why this behavior occurs ? Why are all consequent touches triggering the creation of the fragments and what is with the order of execution of code ?

Secondly,

I am also observing that the owned SKU details aren't being fetched if there is no network connectivity. (I am currently testing with 'android.test.purchased' SKU which happens to be the default provided by Google In-app billing code.) Will this problem be solved if i am having a valid SKU in place ?

Comment: You need to see all places where you adjust static variable. Try to put breakpoints there and see why it gets reset

Comment: got it. My bad. in onDestroy() method i was resetting it to false. Thanks. I still can't figure out why i am not able to fetch the sku details though. Isn't it stored along with the SKU's ?